# There is a duplicate 'oracle.manageddataaccess.client' section defined

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an ASP.NET MVC Application. Its version is *.NET 4.5.2*. It is facilitating Entity Framework and it is using Oracle Database 19c.
I have found a bug in the application and I solve it. It runs smoothly on my local computer. Whenever I publish the application to an IIS server, I have got the error message below:

> There is a duplicate 'oracle.manageddataaccess.client' section defined

This is the content of [web.config.](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Bfqh8RNTeWLX9LUTxgHS2osyL7qMlRZtcLjYTrPrR1o/edit?usp=share_link)

Failed Request Tracing option is opened in IIS, and it does not report any problem.

Diagnosis of chatGPT is as follows:

> This error message indicates that there are multiple instances of the
> same assembly reference in the application's configuration file,
> typically the web.config file. To resolve the issue, you need to
> remove the duplicate references to the assembly
> oracle.manageddataaccess.client. You can open the web.config file and
> remove the duplicate references, keeping only one instance. Make sure
> to save the changes and then republish the application to the IIS
> server. If you have multiple projects in your solution and are using a
> shared library, you may have referenced the library in multiple
> projects, causing duplicates in the final web.config file. To resolve
> this, you can either remove the references from all but one project,
> or create a binding redirect in the web.config file to direct multiple versions of the assembly to a single version.

I have inspected many solution candidates, and the findings also changed when I changed the publishing of the software.  When I asked my findings to chatGPT, I got the following answers:

> i.    Incorrect IIS configuration: Ensure that the IIS website and
> application pool are set up correctly. 
> ii.   Missing dependencies: Make sure that all necessary .NET Framework versions and
> libraries are installed on the server. 
> iii.  Incorrect application pool identity: Set the application pool identity to a low-privilege user account. 
> vi.   Permissions issues: Ensure that the ASP.NET process identity has
> permission to access the application's files and directories.
> v.    Incorrect web.config settings: Check the web.config file for any
> incorrect settings, such as incorrect database connection strings.
> vii.  Application code errors: Check the event logs or enable failed
> request tracing to see if there is any information about the specific
> error. 
> To resolve the issue, you can try the following steps: i.  Check
> the IIS logs for more information about the error. 
> ii.    Enable Failed
> Request Tracing to get more detailed information about the error.
> iii.  Compare the server's configuration with a working development
> environment to identify any differences.
>  iv.  Try re-deploying the
> application with a clean solution and clean build.
>  If the issue
> persists, it may be helpful to consult the Microsoft ASP.NET MVC
> documentation or seek assistance from a qualified developer or
> consultant.

I have inspected the issue through the website and I found some proposals. 
1-  I renamed *oracle.manageddataaccess.client* to *new.oracle.manageddataaccess.client*. ([How to replace the "oracle.manageddataaccess.client" section of machine.config with web.config section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58324931/how-to-replace-the-oracle-manageddataaccess-client-section-of-machine-config-w)) In this circumstance, my new web.config file is as [follows.](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Bfqh8RNTeWLX9LUTxgHS2osyL7qMlRZtcLjYTrPrR1o/edit?usp=share_link)

In this circumstance, I am getting the error below:

> " Server Error in '/' Application.
> _ Runtime Error Description: An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally,
> another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for
> the first exception. The request has been terminated. "

This is the content of the failed [http request trace](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jkh1z2y7UEU8IO8e3j78njfZYIdgjrk4/view?usp=share_link).

2-  I run the codes in powershell as described here: [oracle.manageddataaccess.client duplicate entry for ASP:NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52647244/oracle-manageddataaccess-client-duplicate-entry-for-aspnet)

> set Oracle_x64=c:\oracle\product\12.1\Client_x64\odp.net set
> Oracle_x86=c:\oracle\product\12.1\Client_x86\odp.net
>
> set OraProvCfg_x64=%Oracle_x64%\bin\4\OraProvCfg set
> OraProvCfg_x86=%Oracle_x86%\bin\4\OraProvCfg
>
> "OraProvCfg_x64" /action:config /force /product:odpm
> /frameworkversion:v4.0.30319 /productversion:4.121.1.0
> /unset:settings\TNS_ADMIN "OraProvCfg_x64" /action:config /force
> /product:odpm /frameworkversion:v4.0.30319 /productversion:4.121.2.0
> /unset:settings\TNS_ADMIN "OraProvCfg_x64" /action:config /force
> /product:odpm /frameworkversion:v4.0.30319 /productversion:4.122.1.0
> /unset:settings\TNS_ADMIN "OraProvCfg_x64" /action:config /force
> /product:odpm /frameworkversion:v4.0.30319 /productversion:4.122.18.3
> /unset:settings\TNS_ADMIN "OraProvCfg_x64" /action:unconfig
> /product:odpm /frameworkversion:v4.0.30319 /productversion:4.121.1.0
> "OraProvCfg_x64" /action:unconfig /product:odpm
> /frameworkversion:v4.0.30319 /productversion:4.121.2.0
> "OraProvCfg_x64" /action:unconfig /product:odpm
> /frameworkversion:v4.0.30319 /productversion:4.122.1.0
> "OraProvCfg_x64" /action:unconfig /product:odpm
> /frameworkversion:v4.0.30319 /productversion:4.122.18.3
>
> "OraProvCfg_x86" /action:config /force /product:odpm
> /frameworkversion:v4.0.30319 /productversion:4.121.1.0
> /unset:settings\TNS_ADMIN "OraProvCfg_x86" /action:config /force
> /product:odpm /frameworkversion:v4.0.30319 /productversion:4.121.2.0
> /unset:settings\TNS_ADMIN "OraProvCfg_x86" /action:config /force
> /product:odpm /frameworkversion:v4.0.30319 /productversion:4.122.1.0
> /unset:settings\TNS_ADMIN "OraProvCfg_x86" /action:config /force
> /product:odpm /frameworkversion:v4.0.30319 /productversion:4.122.18.3
> /unset:settings\TNS_ADMIN "OraProvCfg_x86" /action:unconfig
> /product:odpm /frameworkversion:v4.0.30319 /productversion:4.121.1.0
> "OraProvCfg_x86" /action:unconfig /product:odpm
> /frameworkversion:v4.0.30319 /productversion:4.121.2.0
> "OraProvCfg_x86" /action:unconfig /product:odpm
> /frameworkversion:v4.0.30319 /productversion:4.122.1.0
> "OraProvCfg_x86" /action:unconfig /product:odpm
> /frameworkversion:v4.0.30319 /productversion:4.122.18.3

It has no avail.

3-  The problem may be due to name conflict between *machine.config* and *web.config*. Technical description of the situation is as follows:  ([Oracle ODP.NET error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33312848/oracle-odp-net-error))

> If your application is a web application and the above entry was added
> to a web.config and the same config section handler for
> "oracle.manageddataaccess.client" also exists in machine.config but
> the "Version" attribute values are different, an error message of
> "There is a duplicate 'oracle.manageddataaccess.client' section
> defined." may be observed at runtime. If so, the config section
> handler entry in the machine.config for
> "oracle.manageddataaccess.client" has to be removed from the
> machine.config for the web application to not encounter this error.
> But given that there may be other applications on the machine that
> depended on this entry in the machine.config, this config section
> handler entry may need to be moved to all of the application's .NET
> config file on that machine that depend on it.

So I deleted the *oracle.manageddataaccess.client* from the *web.config* file, but the problem persists. I deleted the *oracle.manageddataaccess.client* from the *machine.config* file from the IIS server, the IIS server didn’t work.
I had asked the question to Microsoft Asp.NET MVC forums, however, the question has been deleted on the grounds that “this content has been deleted for violating community guidelines.” (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1166514/server-error-in-application-error)

How can I solve the problem? Any other suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved by creating a freshly installed operating system and IIS server. Previously, IIS has populated from a real server. I suspect that the problem originates because of this, when I create a freshly installed operating system and IIS server and publish there, the problem has solved.